# Google Maps not working using AngularJS and Bootstrap in Android

Tags: android, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps, ibm-mobilefirst

I am developing a Hybrid mobile application using IBM Worklight 6.2.0 on Android and iOS.

I am using AngularJS with BootstrapUI.
It runs on a browser and on iOS devices, but I am facing issues with Google Maps integration on Android devices.

I have tried many possible solutions but none worked.

Below is my code:

```
<style>
    #content,#map_canvas {
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 40px !important;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 40px !important;
    left: 0 !important;
}
</style>

<script>
    var map, currentLocation, currentLocationMarker;
    function loadMapScript() {
        alert("Loading map plz wait : ");
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.id = "googleMaps"
        script.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initializeMap";
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }

    function initializeMap() {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(currentLocation.coords.latitude,
                currentLocation.coords.longitude);
        var mapOptions = {
            center : myLatlng,
            zoom : 18,
            mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                mapOptions);

        updateCurrentLocationMarker();
    }

    function updateCurrentLocationMarker() {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(currentLocation.coords.latitude,
                currentLocation.coords.longitude);

        if (currentLocationMarker) {
            currentLocationMarker.setMap(null);
        } else {
            currentLocationMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position : myLatlng,
                animation : google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                title : "You!",
                map : map
            });
        }
    }

    function onSuccess(position) {
        alert("onSuccess called : ");
        currentLocation = position;
        if (!map) {
            loadMapScript();
        }
    }

    function onError(error) {
        alert('code: ' + error.code + '\n' + 'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }

    function onDeviceReady() {
        alert("onDeviceReady called : ");
        if (navigator && navigator.geolocation) {
        alert("everthing is fine");
            //navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
            WL.Device.Geo.acquirePosition(onSuccess, onError);
        } else {
            alert("issue");
        }
    }

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
</script>

<div id="content">
    <div id="map_canvas"
        style="padding: 0; position: absolute !important; top: 1px !important; right: 0; bottom: 1px !important; left: 0 !important;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Post what you had tried.

Comment: Which device? OS version? What's "not working"? Any errors in LogCat?

Comment: Hi Idan,
Thanks for your help.
I am trying to run it on any Android Device with OS 4.0+
It works on a browser or iOS device. And this code is a separate partial HTML file that is loaded (as it is an SPA)

Will share my proj shortly.

Comment: Hello, I cannot get the map to zoom in/out.The default zoom controls do not get triggred on zoom pinch nor the plus minus buttons are triggering.I have tried with the following map options.


var mapOptions = { zoom: 8, center: myLatlng, panControl: false, zoomControl: true, minZoom: 4, maxZoom: 21, scaleControl: false, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };

Answer (score 2):

The URL was blocked by my whitelist in config.xml.Adding ;  to config.xml in my native folder worked.:)